# asp .net core with angular, high memory in node process (always growing)

Tags: node.js, angular, asp.net-core, server-side-rendering

I have app using asp .net core angular and publish in linux ubuntu.

It works,  but memory usage reach 100 % after several hour.
(I need to restart kestrel after that),

When look at processes, the node process is always growing in memory:

[image]

Comment: Do you have any suspicious part of your code? If yes can we see the code. I'm sorry without more information I'm not able to help

Comment: @JanithKasun: i dont know where to start looking because asp .net who responsible to start node. i can show you node command tmp file : https://pastebin.com/cwHrCpj6

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.